# Protractor: Create Global Variable for multiple instances of one test

Tags: variables, protractor, global

I have set multiCapabilities to run cross browser test. I need a Global variable to be initialized before launching multiple parallel instances of one test that can be single describe() or single it() function. And then I want to use same initialized Global variable inside test cases when test is running. Please, provide a way to do this in Protractor. As we can do same thing in Testng easily using @BeforeTest or @BeforeClass and @AfterTest or @AfterClass. But in protractor I can't find anything related to them. And BeforeAll of protractor is not working as it is being run multiple times as the number of browsers we have provided in multiCapabilities, creating multiple variables instead of one Global variable for all the instances.

Comment: Could you give us more information as to what framework/language are you working with? The answer can be very different if you are using Java or Javascript, for example.

Comment: @JoaquinCasco I am using Jasmine framework with protractor using node-js. I have a library in node-js which needs to be used in test. For that, the main class of library should be initialized once for parallel instances of one test. Thats why i need global instance before launching multiple instances. I tried with beforeLaunch but we can't access any variable initialized in beforeLaunch in our test.

Comment: Can't you just create an object file with variables inside and export the file ?

Comment: @JoaquinCasco I tried that also but in that case both instances fetching object value differently means after launching the browsers. But I want something like beforeLaunch but its variable should be accessed outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start protractor with environment variable like this

```
MY_VAR=Dev protractor tmp/config.js
```

And then it will be available in your config

```
console.log(process.env.MY_VAR)
```

Comment: But how I'll initialize this variable using CMD. Because the variable needs to be an instance of a class of another library. And if I have multiple spec files then I need multiple instances, how I can do that through this approach?......Actually I need something like----  1GlobalVariable for One Spec File, 2nd GlobalVariable for Second Spec File. And Respective Global Variable should be initialized once for their spec file and to be used in parallel instances (multiCapabilities) of the same spec file.